# What controller is used for product list on main page in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop

I have some discounts depending on stock quantity and would like to show the lowest price for each product on product list page (both in categories and on main page).

So I found [this](http://nemops.com/lowest-price-prestashop-product-list/#.VXgs9XWUexU) tutorial that explains how this behavior can be achieved.

So I created override behavior for both `CategoryController` and `ProductController` but changes aren't displayed on main page.

Product List on main page uses the same template, `product-list.tpl` but controller is obviously different. And I can't figure out which one I should override now.

Comment: It seems to suggest the issue is `on line 46` - any clues? What's on that line?

Comment: I updated the question. This error is only slightly related to my actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Product list on main page is displayed by HomeFeatured plugin, so to alter Product objects on main page I had to add extra code to `_cacheProducts()` method and alter `HomeFeatured::$cache_products` there.

I had to do that right in my plugin code since my Prestashop version is 1.6.0.8 and module overriding is available only [since 1.6.0.11 release](http://nemops.com/override-prestashop-modules-core/#.VXg25nWUexV).